# Updating column with Null value

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, sqldatasource, dbnull

I have a date field (smalldatetime) in a table and in particular cases I need to set the date field to null. Currently, when setting the sqlparameter.value property to a date

`endDateParam.Value = "5/15/2011"`

the field is updated with the proper date. However, setting it to

`endDateParam.Value = System.DbNull.Value`

doesn't update the field.

Code behind:

```
Protected Sub ...
    For Each r As GridViewRow In gvEmployees.Rows
        SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand = "<stored proc>"
        SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure
        setParameters(r)
        gvEmployees.UpdateRow(r.RowIndex, False)
    Next
End Sub

Private updateParameters As New List(Of SqlParameter)()

Protected Sub setParameters(ByVal r As GridViewRow)
    updateParameters.Clear()

    Dim endDate As TextBox = TryCast(r.FindControl("txtEndDate"), TextBox)

    Dim endDateParam As New SqlParameter("@enddate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime)
    endDateParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    endDateParam.Value = System.DBNull.Value
    updateParameters.Add(endDateParam)
End Sub

Protected Sub Sqldatasource1_Updating(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs)
    e.Command.Parameters.Clear()
    For Each p As SqlParameter In updateParameters
        e.Command.Parameters.Add(p)
    Next
End Sub
```

**Update**

`endDateParam.Value = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.Null`

Still doesn't seem to update the field. No errors are returned.

Comment: What does happen? Errors? Exceptions? Nothing?

Comment: Just a thought, is it possible the stored procedure does something when it sees a NULL parameter?  What ends up in the endDate field in the table?

Comment: @Sparky - You were right. Within that sproc, we execute 2 others, one of which, after looking into it, was exiting based on a null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SqlDateTime.Null](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.null.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try  SqlDateTime.Null  instead of system.dbnull.value

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use Sql Profiler to see exactly what is getting sent to the server.  That should help you narrow down the problem